# Full Code vs. Suggested conceptual explanation fix

Tags: discussion

My question is similar to this: [Answers with too much code and too little explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184720/answers-with-too-much-code-and-too-little-explanation)

I recently posted on this question: [Why doesn't my "While Loop" print the computation of finding the average "score"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727896/why-doesnt-my-while-loop-print-the-computation-of-finding-the-average-score/19727962#19727962) My answer simply explains the concept the OP is missing. What is better: the people below who posted the full code answer or my conceptual explanation? Please let me know if this is a dup and I will take it down. I just couldn't find an actual discussion of the teach a man to fish verse give a man a fish question.

Comment: It looks a lot better now. A comment and time brought improvement.

Comment: @BillWoodger Are you referring to the specific question?

Comment: Yes. I suggested to the person with the largest piece of code that they do some explanation, as it was a beginner asking the question and they might be too daunted to run the code due to the many changes. Turns out he was answering from in his math class. Thought the explanations were a good idea.

Comment: @BillWoodger yeah I am answering from my internship. Same problem

Comment: Good for you too. If short of time, I think doing the explanation of the problem first is the best way - given that no advice can fit every circumstance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends entirely on you.  Different people feel differently about this topic, as they are entitled to.  No matter what you do there are going to be some people that feel you didn't provide something that you should have (either code or explanation) or that you provided something that you shouldn't have.  At some point you just need to make a choice that you can live with for each question you come across.

Context also matters; based on the question being asked some users are clearly looking for an explanation of a concept; their question makes it clear that they want to understand why something isn't working, not just to get a code snippet that doesn't have the same problem.  Other questions make it clear that they have no interest in understanding concepts; they want code or nothing at all.  You should take this into consideration when forming your answer.  You may choose not to honor those perceived or explicit requests (I know I've responded to gimmie teh codez questions with nothing but an explanation before) but be warned that such answers are not always well received (either by the author or even other community members).

Another contextual consideration to make is how important you feel the core concept of that answer is; can someone effectively utilize the code in an answer without knowing some of what you've explained?  Are explanations to those concepts accessible elsewhere, or would they have a hard time understanding the code if they later wanted to know more about what's going on?  If you just provide an explanation will the code be simple and follow directly?  Will the explanation provide keywords that they can search on that they didn't know of before to allow them to find the solution?  As always, you're free to determine how much you want to weight these options, but these are some of the considerations that readers of your code will likely have in mind.

Keep in mind that it's also not a strictly boolean decision; you can decide how in depth of an explanation you want to give, not just *if* you give one.  You can decide on to what degree to expand on the concepts surrounding the question.  When giving code you can vary between giving nothing to a few snippets showing the meat of the problem, or the part they're likely struggling with, to a full SSCCE, or something in-between, based on your perceived willingness and ability of the readers of such a question to get to a final solution from what you provide.

Answer (score 7):

The best option? Give them both.

That satisfies both the immediate need - what's the answer **and** explains the conceptual problem, giving the OP both a fish and teaches them how to fish.

Comment: Except for all of the people that just copy the code and ignore the text...

Comment: @Servy - they have needs too. Not everyone wants to learn how to fish...